# The first row index the number is smaller than

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have two tables

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I like to add a column to first table. This column shall contain the lowest column number from table 2 for which the value in table 1 is smaller than. This comparison should be done respect to the ID number. The desired result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: So what's your question? You've stated what you want, but that's it. If you know what you need to do, you don't need our permission to do so; but if you feel you need it, you have mine.

Comment: There is no need to be cocky. Obviously I need some help or guide to do this. I might add, that I tried to solve it with while loops, but it got quite messy and it didn't work out for me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm not being "cocky" at all. Stack Overflow is a website for asking questions; we can't help you if you don't have a question. "Can you guide me" isn't a question, and would be considered to broad for SO. If you have made some attempts, then please do show those in your question, when you edit it to ask us something we can help you with. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). once we know what you're asking, then the volunteers will be more than happy to try and answer it (including myself).

Comment: So to that question I am not totally sure. I am using Azure data warehouse through SQL server management studio. Is that enough answer?

Comment: @Larnu, sure. I agree, but your last sentence didn't add anything to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the assumption that the values in the second table are in ascending order, and that the id is unique in the second table.

It will also, for example return "6" if the value in the first table is larger than all of them, even though there are only 5 columns, but that should be relatively easy to handle.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (id CHAR(1), val FLOAT);
CREATE TABLE #t2 (id CHAR(1), col1 FLOAT, col2 FLOAT, col3 FLOAT, col4 FLOAT, col5 FLOAT);

INSERT INTO #t1 
VALUES ('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('a',2);

INSERT INTO #t2
VALUES  ('a',1,2,3,4,5),
        ('b',1,1.5,2,10,11),
        ('c',-1,1,1.5,3,4);

-- unpivot the data into key value pairs
SELECT  id, name, val
INTO #t2u 
FROM 
(
SELECT *
from #t2
) a
UNPIVOT
(
val
FOR name IN ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5])
) u

-- now count how many are less than or equal then add 1 because we want the next col
SELECT #t1.id, 
    #t1.val,
    COUNT(*) + 1
FROM #t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #t2u ON #t2u.id = #t1.id
    AND #t2u.val <= #t1.val
GROUP BY #t1.id,
         #t1.val;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a very nice solution! I learned quite a lot from it.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Please upvote and accept the answer to give me glorious Internet Points